# Out of bounds array And No line found Scanner:1516 Error

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I know what an out of bounds error is, and I have research the 1516 error. But when I try to fix my code I get an error either way.  I think that it has to do with my while loop running infinitely, but I cant debug it.

Exact errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at Invest.makeCfPanel(Invest.java:131)
    at Invest.main(Invest.java:25)

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
    at Invest.makeCfPanel(Invest.java:131)
    at Invest.main(Invest.java:25)
```

this is my txt PASTEBUCKET.COM/2303

and my code is

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Invest extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Dimension minSize = new Dimension(1000,500);
    frame.setMinimumSize(minSize);
    frame.setTitle("Financial Calculator | Financial Statment Driven Ratios");

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    //Income Statement Panel
    JComponent panel1 = makeIsPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Income Statement", panel1);
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);
    //Balance Sheet Panel   
    JComponent panel2 = makeBsPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Balance Sheet", panel2);
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);
    //Cash Flows Panel  
    JComponent panel3 = makeCfPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Cash Flows ", panel3);
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_3);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    frame.add(tabbedPane);

    JPanel bottompanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    bottompanel.setBackground(new Color(150, 150, 150));
    frame.add(bottompanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton compute = new JButton("Compute Ratios");
    bottompanel.add(compute);


    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

protected static JComponent makeIsPanel() {
      String[] columnNames = {"Entry", "Year", "Year", "Year", "Year"};

    Object[][] data = {{"Period Ending:", "2011", "Snowboarding", Integer.valueOf(5), false},
        {"Values in Millions of $", "12-31", "Rowing", Integer.valueOf(3), true},
        {"Revenue:", "46,542", "Knitting", Integer.valueOf(2), false},
        {"Revenue Other:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Total Revenue:", "46,542", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Cost of Revenue:", "18,216", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Gross Profit:", "28,326", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Selling Gen. Admin Expenses:", "12,111", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Research & Development:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Depreciation/Amortization:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Total Operating Expense:", "154", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Operating Income:", "35,810", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Interest Income (Exp.), Net NonOp:", "10,732", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Interest/Invest Inc. Non-Operating:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Interest Inc. Net Non-Operating:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Gain/Loss on Sale of Assets:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Other, Net:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Net Income Before Taxes:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Income Tax - Total:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Minority Interest:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Equity In Affiliates:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Accounting Change:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Discontinued Operations:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Extraordinary Items:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Net Income:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false}};
    JPanel isPanel = new JPanel();
    JTable isTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(isTable);
    isPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return isPanel;
}

    protected static JComponent makeBsPanel() {
    String[] columnNames = {"Entry", "Year", "Year", "Year", "Year"};
Object[][] data = {{"Period Ending:", "2011", "Snowboarding", Integer.valueOf(5), false},
        {"Values in Millions of $", "12-31", "Rowing", Integer.valueOf(3), true},
        {"Cash:", "46,542", "Knitting", Integer.valueOf(2), false},
        {"Cash and Cash Equivalents:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Short Term Investments:", "46,542", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Cash and Short Term Investments:", "18,216", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Accounts Recievable- Trade, Net:", "28,326", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Total Receivables, Net:", "12,111", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Total Inventory:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Prepaid Expenses:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Other Current Assets, Total:", "154", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Total Current Assets:", "35,810", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Propert/Plant/Equipment - Gross:", "10,732", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Accumulated Depreciation,Total:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Property/Plant/Equipment - Net:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Gain/Loss on Sale of Assets:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Other, Net:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Net Income Before Taxes:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Income Tax - Total:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Minority Interest:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Equity In Affiliates:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Accounting Change:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Discontinued Operations:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Extraordinary Items:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Net Income:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false}};

    JPanel bsPanel = new JPanel();
    JTable bsTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(bsTable);
    bsPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return bsPanel;
}
    protected static JComponent makeCfPanel() throws IOException {
    String[] columnNames = {"Entry","Year","Year", "Year", "Year", "Year","Year","Year", "Year", "Year", "Year"};

    File f = new File ("data/IS.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(f);


        Object [][] fs = new String[53][11];

            while (input.hasNextLine())
            {   
                for (int col=0;col<53;col++){
                    for (int row=0;row<11;row++){
                        fs[row][col] = input.nextLine();
                    //  System.out.printf("%s\t",fs[row][col]);
                    }
                }
                if (input.hasNextLine()) 
                    input.nextLine();

            }


    /*Object[][] data = {{"Period Ending:", "2011", "Snowboarding", Integer.valueOf(5), false},
        {"Values in Millions of $", "12-31", "Rowing", Integer.valueOf(3), true},
        {"Revenue:", "46,542", "Knitting", Integer.valueOf(2), false},
        {"Revenue Other:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Total Revenue:", "46,542", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Cost of Revenue:", "18,216", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Gross Profit:", "28,326", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Selling Gen. Admin Expenses:", "12,111", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Research & Development:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Depreciation/Amortization:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Total Operating Expense:", "154", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Operating Income:", "35,810", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Interest Income (Exp.), Net NonOp:", "10,732", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Interest/Invest Inc. Non-Operating:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Interest Inc. Net Non-Operating:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Gain/Loss on Sale of Assets:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Other, Net:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Net Income Before Taxes:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Income Tax - Total:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
        {"Minority Interest:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Equity In Affiliates:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Accounting Change:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Discontinued Operations:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Extraordinary Items:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
        {"Net Income:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false}};*/
    JPanel cfPanel = new JPanel();
    JTable cfTable = new JTable(fs, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(cfTable);
    cfPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return cfPanel;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Scanner` is never queried within the nested `for` loop to determine if it `hasNextLine()` before `nextLine()` is called and `nextLine()` throws `NoSuchElementException` if there is no next line.

You need to either handle that exception or protect `nextLine()` within the `for`, and decide what it means for there to be less lines that expected.

The indexes into the array are in the wrong order, causing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Change to:

```
fs[col][row] = input.nextLine();
```

Consider querying the array for its dimensions in the `for` loops instead of repeating the hard-coded values:

```
for (int col = 0, col_size = fs.length; col < col_size; col++)
{
    for (int row = 0, row_size = fs[col].length; row < row_size; row++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks.  When you say protected, I'm not quite following. I could see how I would copy it into another variable... so protecting it that way? But it seems that doesn't accomplish much.

Comment: By protect I mean have a `input.hasNextLine()` prior to the `input.nextLine()` inside the `for`. If the there is no next line then you need to decide what it means for the application: failure or is appropriate default values that could be used to populate the elements of the array that are currently not set?

Comment: makes sense.  So I put an if statement before the nested loops, as well as a and else closes the loop.

Comment: No, you need it inside the `for`, directly before the `nextLine()`.

Comment: `nextLine()` throws if there are no more lines. There is a single check for `nextLine()` made and then `nextLine()` is called `53 * 11` times!

Comment: haha, well that would do it. Looks like that bug as been fixed.  But i need to fix the loop order again.  I need to fill the array column by column, instead of row by row.